# a problem about rabbitmq's Acknowledgement Modes

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I know consumer Delivery Acknowledgements divided by manual or automatic modes. But in my opinion，the concept of Delivery Acknowledgements is the same in manual modes. Automatic modes is deleted immediately after message sent, where have a relationship with ack?

I found the official docs [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUWIk.png)

I think the automatic modes is when consumer reveived a message, it doesn't handle following steps , it do ack to rabbitmq, let it deletes the message from queue.

I hope to get a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

The diffrent in consumer Delivery Acknowledgements about manual or automatic modes is that the consumer get the message will give a ack message to RabbitMQ ,RabbitMQ will delete the message from the Queue.
In fact ,your consumer to consume a message need some time, the consume time length is  due to your code runtime.
Assuming your consumer send the ack to your Rabbitmq, your system will lost the message.
But if you are manual ack to the RabbitMQ,your RabbitMQ will know your consumer has encounter some problem,it will delivery the message to other consumer.
On the other hand, if your consumer failed to consume the message,you can simple send no ack to RabbitMQ to ensure your message will have a right consume.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following scenario: A consumer is responsible for processing and inserting a message into a database. However, the consumer restarts soon after receiving the message and is unable to process and insert the data into the database. Meanwhile, the broker deletes the message as it has been consumed. This issue can be prevented by manually choosing to `ack` the message.

You can reduce inflight transaction failures to a reasonable extent with manual acknowledgement.

I have prepared this use case for a [demo sometime back](https://github.com/govindkailas/rabbitmq-operator-demo/tree/main), you may refer how `consumer1` is working.